# Change the size of a particular piece of text

Tags: fontsize

I want to increase the size of a particular text. Suppose I want to write the following:

```
"I am a hungry cat
I want to drink the rains
I am not thirsty"
```

I want the middle line to be written in big and I want the 1st and 3rd line to write very small. How can I do that?

Comment: The basic font can be altered with `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, and `\small` in the smaller direction.  It can go larger with `\large`, `\Large`, ...[a few more]...all the way up to `\Huge`.  See Lamport's LaTeX reference book for more specifics..

Comment: why have you tagged this as math-mode?

Comment: ...the link I provided references a change in font, but applied to font-size as well. If the link does not answer your question, please provide some feedback as to why this is not the case. Then, provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current behaviour. Without constraint there are many solutions to your problem, but they may not all fit your use-case, hence the request for a MWE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can influence the font size as following:

```
{\tiny Text of first line}
{\Large Text of second line}
{\tiny Text of third line}
```